# IP Spoofing at the IP level

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I'm just reading about TCP and UDP and from what I've read when the packet gets encapsulated in the IP protocol and the header gets added is it not possible to create a false IP address at this stage?

Granted, the response will never be received on your connection, but is this possible?

I do not want to do this btw. I'm in no way associated with immoral ethics. It's just something that I had to ask whilst reading about TCP and UDP. I'm actually learning how to use sockets in C++ for a game I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

- Use raw sockets and craft your own packets
- Use scapy, hping, etc
- Search for "packet crafting"

#### EDIT

A nice `scapy` tutorial that teaches you to send lots of valid and invalid stuff is [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#interactive-tutorial).